# rails button_to current_user correct path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button-to

What path can I use to display a `current_user`'s own listed products?

```
= button_to "View My Products", root_path, method: :get, class: "button"
```

Instead of `root_path` I tried to use `@product.user.all` which did not work.

Thanks!

edit:

```
            user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
     search_products GET    /products/search(.:format)     products#search
            products GET    /products(.:format)            products#index
                     POST   /products(.:format)            products#create
         new_product GET    /products/new(.:format)        products#new
        edit_product GET    /products/:id/edit(.:format)   products#edit
             product GET    /products/:id(.:format)        products#show
                     PATCH  /products/:id(.:format)        products#update
                     PUT    /products/:id(.:format)        products#update
                     DELETE /products/:id(.:format)        products#destroy
       welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)       welcome#index
                root GET    /                              welcome#index
```

and all of Devise's standard routes.

Comment: Can you post your routes?

Comment: updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want one product controller index action and association between user and products

Then in products#index action

```
def index
  @products = current_user.products
end
```

and your link will be

```
= link_to 'View My Products', {controller: :products, action: :index}
```

If your product#index action for non authenticated users then make that action conditional
like
`@products = (current_user ? current_user.products : Product.all)`